# How do I simplify $\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ when $f(x)=x^3-x$?

Tags: calculus

I'm having a hard time simplifying this math equation? Please help?

Comment: How far can you get?

Comment: while it's good to know the binomial theorem and that $(x+h)^3 = x^3+3hx^2+3h^2x+h^3$, note that in this particular problem that that knowledge isn't necessary. you can factor $f(x)=x^3-x=x(x^2-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{((a+h)^3-(a+h))-(a^3-a)}{h}=\frac{a^3+3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3-a-h-a^3+a}{h}=\frac{3a^2h+3ah^2+h^3-h}{h} \\ =3a^2+3ah+h^2-1=h^2+3ah+3a^2-1$$

Comment: Thank you so much. I see what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need the binomial theorem

> $$ (a+b)^3 = a^3+3a^2b + 3ab^2+b^3  $$

Answer (score 0):

$f(a+h)=(a+h)^3-(a+h)=a^3+3ah^2+3a^2h+h^3-(a+h)$.

So, $f(a+h)-f(a)=(a^3+3ah^2+3a^2h+h^3-(a+h))-((a^3)-a)=h(3ah+3a^2+h^2-1)$